# FileMaker Server not connecting to host/port in admin-console

Tags: networking, installation, webserver, filemaker

I'm trying to install FileMaker Server with web publishing. When I get to this screen:

[image: FileMaker Server]

As you can see, it keeps saying connection refused no matter port I use. If I change the host, it still says 127.0.0.1 in the log below it. What am I doing wrong? All the ports I'm trying are forwarded already too.

Answer (score 0):

Port needs to be open in the firewall (not the one between you and the outside world) - the one on the machine that FMS is running on, which is where it's going to run its own webserver, by default - other setups are possible but not basic. 127.0.0.1 is, of course, the machine's loopback address.

If setting up the FMS webserver on another machine that other machine needs that part of FMS installed (and then I get vague, as I've only read through it and never actually done mine that way.)